# X710 (i40e) NIC DPDK bind Error in centos 7.3

Tags: dpdk

When I use dpdk-devbind.py to bind a port of Network port of X710. I get error:

*Error: bind failed for 0000:20.00.0 - Cannot bind to driver uio_pci_generic. 
Error: unbind failed for 0000:20:00.0 - Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/drivers//unbind*

The command was run by root user. Linux version is: 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64. It is run in CentOS 7.3.

Same haredware, same command run in CentOS 7 (Linux: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64), the bind work well.

In addition, CentOS 7.3 with Intel X520 work well with dpdk.

Something else: before bind command from dpdp, in CentOS 7, ifconfig cannot view i40e port. but in CentOS 7.3, it can see the ports.

Looks like Linux Kernel problem, but when I upgrade kernel to 4.16 (mainline) or 4.4 (longterm), I get ERST: cannot request mem error. Anything else I can try?

Comment: On the CentOS 7, have you checked the Linux logs (dmesg, syslog)? Is there any error message related to i40e?

Comment: In dmesg: only 1 line: i40e 0000:20:00.1 i40e_ptp_stop: removed PHC on enp32s0f1. In /var/log/messages: there is another line: localhost NetworkManager[933]: <info>  [1524212844.2665] device (enp32s0f1): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [20 10 36]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should bind with igb_uio , generic is not supported for this type of intel controller.